# Reporting Users Login TimeStamps on a Domain

Tags: powershell

StackoverFlow! I am looking for help with my code. Its objective is to take the listed Domain, and to Report to me all the users On the Domain, login Time Stamps.

```
Get_ADUser -Filter * _SearchBase "dc=<nhtool>,dc=<local>" -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,samaccountname,lastLogonTimestamp |
    Select CN,samaccountname,@{n="lastLogonDate";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} |
    Export-CSV -NoType "D:\TEMP\<UserTest.csv>"
```

The Error That I get is:

> `"Get_ADUser : The term 'Get_ADUser' is not recongnized  as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, of if  a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 2) At line:1 Char1: + Get_ADuser -Filter * _Searchbase "dc=,nhtool>,dc=<.local>" -ResultPag..... +Categoryinfo :ObjectNotFound (get_ADuser:String_ [], CommandNotFoundException +FullyQualifiedErrorID : CommandNotFoundException`

Any help would be Greatly Appreciated as im New to Powershell!

Comment: What's the question exactly? you forgot to ask it.

Comment: Please add that *to the question*, thanks.

Comment: Now that it's formatted, your problem is syntax.  Cmdlets are in the form of `Verb-Noun`, with a *dash*.  Change your command to use `Get-ADUser`

Comment: Now i get, "Get-ADUser : The supplied distringuishedName must belong to one of the following partitions: 'DC=NHtool,DC=local , CN=Configuration,DC=NHtool,DC=local  , CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=NHtool,DC=local , DC =DomainDNSZones,DC=Nhtool,Dc=local , DC=ForestDNSZones,DC=Nhtool,dc=local

Comment: Did you change some other part of your code?  That doesn't match what you're asking in the question.

Comment: I made Changes to the "Get_ADUser, and then my boss pointed out that using "<" isnt a valid way of specifying a file path or the domain controller

Comment: Oh, I thought those were intentional for obfuscation on a public forum.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All for your Help, The "<" function was what was throwing my code off.
This is the correct Code, Thanks!

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=nhtool,dc=local" -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,samaccountname,lastLogonTimestamp | Select CN,samaccount,@{n="lastLogonDate";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} |
Export-CSV -NoType "D:\temp\UserTest.csv"
```